# Maven Error in pom.xml using spring

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have this error in maven(pom.xml) in InteliIdea :

Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.6.RELEASE from https:// repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.6.RELEASE from/to central (https:// repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset. Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.6.RELEASE from https:// repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.6.RELEASE from/to central (https:// repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset.

How can I fix the problem?
I'm in windows

Comment: Looks like a network problem; possibly a proxy issue. Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score -1):

you can try with the  lower version of the `Spring-boot=stater-parent`, you can try this the version `1.4.6.RELEASE` or `1.3.5.RELEASE`
you can also file the code below :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The lower version will not change a thing related to a network problem..

Comment: yes, this solution worked for me. But why did the upper version fail , couldnt find the reason. anyway thanks.